# Listview: smooth scroll and row update at the same time

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I basically have to smooth scroll a listview and update a row at the same time.
I do it with a simple approach for now:

```
mListViewWeeks.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // update the row concerned
                updateItemAtPosition(rowIndex);

                int duration = 200;
                mListView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(rowIndex, 0, duration);
            }
});
```

with the updateItemAtPosition() function:

```
private void updateItemAtPosition(int position) {
    int visiblePosition = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View view = mListView.getChildAt(position - visiblePosition);
    mListView.getAdapter().getView(position, view, mListView);
}
```

It's working well at a reasonable scroll speed, but when going faster (calling the first block above at a high rate) it can get a bit laggy. Is there anything that I can do to improve updating a row while scrolling smoothly?

Comment: For update the listview you need implements the viewholder pattern http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html your listview would be more efficient and smooth scrollable.

Comment: I use this pattern, this pattern has getView() called when a list item gets visible at the screen. Now how do you update an item, that's already visible at the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm really late in the game. It looks like one of the reason why RecyclerView was introduced. I'm gonna try to use this component from now on.

A combination of `layoutManager.scrollToPosition(position);`

and `adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);` does the job. Everything runs smoothly!!

Answer (score 0):

You should'nt acces the iew dirrectly like this. Instead you should update your model object displayed by the list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your adapter.

Comment: True, I thought that at first. notifyDataSetChanged() makes the UI update worst and getView() looks nice compared to it. Sounds hackish, but that's the best I have so far!

Comment: If you update your model object before calling smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(); you don't need to call notifyDataSetChanged(). getView(..) will be called and automatically update your view according to your Model Object.